# PHP Return results based on two timestamps within 30mins

Tags: php, arrays, datetime, foreach, timestamp

Bit of a newb and I am stuck... so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Bit of a preface, I did have some help earlier, which pretty much achieved what I needed, but it got to the point where I didn't want to take any more of his time anymore (I ask a lot of him already).

I have a base time of '7am' for example, I would like to retrieve 30 minutes of results 'past' 7am, currently with help, I get all results before and after 7am.

Here is the code:

```
    $timeArrayOne = array(array("time"=>"2015-10-01 06:45:00"),array("time"=>"2015-10-01 07:15:00"),array("time"=>"2015-10-01 07:29:00"),array("time"=>"2015-10-01 07:31:00"));
    $msg = '';
    $closest = false;
    $closestResult = false;

        foreach ($timeArrayOne as $result) {
            // foreach to get $basetime
            $loggedTime = $result['time'];

            // Set Base time
            $baseTime = new DateTime("2015-10-01 07:00:00");

            // Set Time Two
            $TimeTwo = new DateTime($loggedTime);

            //  Subtract basetime from Time Two / divide by 60 for minutes
            $minutes = abs(strtotime($baseTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')) - strtotime($TimeTwo->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))) / 60;

            if ($minutes <= 30) {
                $rounded = round($minutes);
                $msg .= "Success - $loggedTime <br/>";
                }
            }

            echo $msg;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Question unclear.. Explain please?

Comment: I would like to get all results past '7am' and not before, within a timespan of 30 mins.

Comment: Where's $minutes >= 0?

Comment: Thanks Paul, Amal's answer worked brilliantly, but thank you for helping out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `strtotime()` and the date manipulations while using DateTime. You can simply compare DateTime objects like so:

```
// Set the base time, which can also be read from input
$baseTime = new DateTime("2015-10-01 07:00:00");

// Add 30 (or any number) of minutes to it
$endTime = clone $baseTime;
$endTime->add(new DateInterval("PT30M"));    

foreach ($timeArrayOne as $result) {
    $loggedTime = $result['time'];
    $TimeTwo = new DateTime($loggedTime);
    if ($TimeTwo >= $baseTime and $TimeTwo <= $endTime) {
        $msg .= "Success - $loggedTime <br/>";
    }
}

echo $msg;
```

This prints out:

```
Success - 2015-10-01 07:15:00 
Success - 2015-10-01 07:29:00
```

Which I think is the expected result here.

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/455536)